Using tkinter to open a dialog box and save an excel workbook of scraped data. it's taking forever
I'm working on a web scraper that scrapes titles, prices and availability of books for a dummy site made specifically for scraping practice. So it goes through the site, gathers all the links for different categories of books, runs through all of them and pulls the title, price and availability of the book (whether or not it is in stock). As it does so for each category, its supposed to load this into an excel workbook, with a sheet for each category. When its done its supposed to open a dialog box to allow user to name and choose where to store the file.
This is the code
from urllib.request import urlopen
from openpyxl import Workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
import re
import requests
import ssl

...
            
def saveworkbook(wb):
    try:
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()  # Hide the root window

        # Ask user to select a file path and name for saving
        file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])

        if file_path:
            # Save the workbook to the specified file path
            wb.save(file_path)
            print(f"Workbook saved to: {file_path}")
        else:
            print("Save operation canceled.")

        # Close the Tkinter root window
        root.destroy()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred with Tkinter: {e}")



I have tested all the parts of the code that gather links, scrape data, etc, by printing them out and looking through them, so i know that the data being scraped is correct and done successfully. Its just the file writing and save that isnt working. There are no errors, it just runs infinitely. The longest I left it was 30 minutes.
I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me by telling me what i did wrong or a better way to accomplish what i'm trying to do.
I'm using vscode, python 3.12

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You create a Tcl interpreter root = Tk() and destroy it every time data is saved!! Try creating one Tk() object during initialization and destroy it once at the end of your session. This will speed things up.

It takes around 3 minutes to complete scraper() and saveworkbook() works fine for me. Note that you don't need to create instance of Tk() explicitly because asksaveasfilename() will create it implicitly if there is no instance of Tk().
